# Stop refresh event in customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

How can I stop the `refresh` event for the Customizer iframe? Something like:

```
wp.customize.refresh( function() {
    return; // or whatever would stop the refresh
} );
```

The background:  I'm using Kirki to add a code editor field to the front end Customizer.  It gets an option from my theme option's custom CSS area (not a theme I developed, so I cannot use traditional theme_mod) and I can properly get/put the data from this option to write custom CSS from the front end Customizer.

For the live edit to work, I modified the front end custom CSS `<style>` element to have a unique ID, and using CodeMirror's `update` event I can replace the `<style>` element's contents successfully and see the live changes. However, the Customizer `refresh` event also fires just moments after, thus wiping out the updated `<style>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/

Using 'transport' => 'postMessage' in my fields settings array.  Kirki also provides passing this option too.